# Printing filename along with grep results in find -exec

Tags: command-line, grep, find, filenames

I have a program called `foo` which I want to exec on each result that is found via find.  So something like this:

`find . -name '*.o' -type f -exec foo {} \;`

I want to grep the output of all of these invocations of `foo` for a certain string bar.  So I add this:

`find . -name '*.o' -type f -exec foo {} \; | grep bar`

But I lose the original information about what files the matches are coming from.  I tried adding `-fprintf /dev/stderr '%p\n'` to the `find` command but now it looks like stdout is gone, because no grep results are printed.

How can I get each filename printed to the output and THEN have the grep results corresponding to that file printed after?

Alternatively, if there were some way to make the `-H` argument of `grep` work that would be fine too, but as written it won't work because I'm just passing text from stdin, and `grep` doesn't know the filename.  I tried various incantations of `xargs`, but I couldn't get any of that to work either.

Comment: Does your `grep` support a `--label` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get each filename printed to the output and THEN have the grep results corresponding to that file printed after, you could wrap the `-exec foo {} | grep` pipe in a shell:

```
find . -name '*.o' -type f -print -exec sh -c 'foo "$1" | grep "bar"' sh {} \;
```

To to make the `-H` argument of grep work with standard input, if your version of `grep` supports the `--label=` option you could do

```
find . -name '*.o' -type f -exec sh -c '
  foo "$1" | grep -H --label="$1" "bar"
' sh {} \;
```

or (if your find supports the `+` multi-argument alternative to `\;`):

```
find . -name '*.o' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f; do foo "$f" | grep -H --label="$f" "bar"; done
' sh {} +
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but what is `$1`?

Comment: @ZacharyTurner `$1` is the first argument (positional parameter) passed to the `sh -c` shell command; in effect, `{}` outside the shell becomes `$1` inside the shell when we use `find . . . {} \;` (and becomes a parameter *list* `$@` when we use the `find . . . +` GNU extension).

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get each filename printed to the output and THEN have the
>   grep results corresponding to that file printed after?

**1.)** use two instances of grep, one for printing the filename and another one for printing the match:

```
find . -name '*.o' -type f -exec grep -l bar {} \; -exec grep bar {} \;
```

**2.)** make grep behave as if it was multiple files:

```
find . -name '*.o' -type f -exec grep bar {} /dev/null \;
```

this does not solve the problem with `[..]-exec foo {} \;[...]` and running grep within a pipe as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty ugly, but it will work for you:

```
find . -name '*.o' -type f -exec sh -c 'foo "$1" | sed "s@^@$1\t@"' _ {} \;
```

That will put the filename and a tab at the start of each line. The bare underscore is a string  that populates `$0` in the spawned shell, leaving the filename as `$1`. Now you can grep the output of find, and the filename will appear in the output.

---

That will break for any filenames containing the `@` character. If that's a concern, we can augment the shell script:

```
find . -name '*.o' -type f -exec sh -c '
    r=$(echo "$1" | sed "s/@/\\\\\\\\@/g")
    foo "$1" | sed "s@^@$r\t@"
' _ {} \;
```

8 backslashes were determined by trial and error ...

Or using bash (or ksh) which has a convenient "search and replace" parameter substitution

```
find . -name '*.o' -type f -exec ksh -c 'foo "$1" | sed "s@^@${1//@/\\\\@}\t@"' _ {} \;
```